# Parse a value to a class from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to read a user input text file (This file would be a ".java" or ".c++" file) in run time and do some calculations. I use MVC architecture to implement this.

**What I've done so far;**

GetFileServlet

```
FileService fileService = new FileService();
Files files = new Files();
SizeService sizeService = new SizeService();

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);

    String value = request.getParameter("code");

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\"+value);

    String path = file.toString();

    files.setFile(path);
    sizeService.getFile();

    // Read the URL in the file object
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    // Create a empty String variable

        // int count = 0;

        String text;
        // Read the file till it's end
        try {
            while ((text  = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(st);

                // Display the file in the web page
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println(text);
            }
            files.setCode(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In this class (GetFileServlet), I get the file from user and read the whole file and send the value of that file and path to another class called SizeService.java. In this class, I can get the path of that file but I can't get the   text from that file. It gives me a null value. This values parsing through class called Files.java. When I pass the text into this class, its print the text. But when I try to access it from the SizeService.java class by using a getter, it doesn't print. Please help me to solve this.

And also I need a better way to get the file path insted of this;

```
    String value = request.getParameter("code");
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\"+value);
```

These are the Other classes;

SizeService.java

```
public class SizeService {

Files files = new Files();

public String getFile() {
    String code = files.getCode();
    System.out.println(code + " im in the service"); // This give me a null value
    return code;

}
```

}

Files.java

public class Files {

```
private static String file;
private static String code; 


public Files() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Files(String file, String code) {
    super();
    Files.code = code;
    Files.file = file;

}

public static String getFile() {
    return file;

}

public void setFile(String file) {
    Files.file = file;

}

public static String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    Files.code = code;
}
```

}

Comment: Where does `sizeService` (The line `sizeService.getFile();`) come from?

Comment: Its a method in the SizeService.java

Comment: No, `sizeService` is either a field or a variable. It's not a method.

Comment: Oh yeah sizeService is an object. There is a class called SizeService.java. I'm trying to access a method inside it

Comment: And how is `sizeService` declared and assigned?

Comment: I have declared an object in GetFilesServlet.  SizeService sizeService = new SizeService();

Comment: You should somehow share the Files instance. You create two, and they have different fields. as expected.

Comment: I made the fields static but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
files.setFile(path);
sizeService.getFile();
```

These two lines are problematic. "files" is a non-static attribute of sizeService class and getFile() method is not static either. Both of them can be used only if you have declared an object in first class.
 something like

```
sizeService sobject =new sizeService();
```

then  reference the files object as 
`sobject.files....`
and use the getFile method as `sobect.getFile()....`

Another alternative is that you make the "files" and "getFile()" both static. So that in another class you can reference them directly like

```
sizeService.files.....  sizeSrvice.getFile().....
```

Comment: Another problem is the way you declare the files attribute in your sizeService class. Mostly attributes are declared as private and that is the default. And if you really want to access it directly in other classes by making it static, you have to declare it as public as well, as a public static attribute, which is very rare, but probably still works